# How to make LinearGradient work for 3D graph in Qt

Tags: linux, qt

I have a 3D graph in Qt . I have applied linear gradient to the plot but there is no effect on the plot.My code is below.Is it because of the negative values on the Y axis,Please help

```
QLinearGradient gr;
gr.setColotAt(0.0,Qt::black);
gr.setColorAt(0.33,Qt::blue);
gr.setColorAt(0.67,Qt::red);
gr.setColorAt(1.0,Qt::yellow);
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it. and also did you see [Surface Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html) Example?

Comment: `m_graph->seriesList().at(0)->setBaseGradient(gr);
m_graph->seriesList().at(0)->setColorStyle(Q3DTheme::ColorStyleRangeGradient);`

Comment: Yes Thank you but I took the surface example as reference and also added the lines that you have mentioned but no effect.

Comment: Could this be because of the negative values on the Y axis.

Comment: I should see your code and test it, maybe it happens because of your GPU or something like that. If you can add it in one `Github` repo or  provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Parisa.H.R can you please let me know ur email id so that I can mail it to you